# Matrix to the power t.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

Compute the matrix $A^t$ for the following cases:

$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \quad  A_2=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad  A_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},  \quad  A_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},  \quad  A_5=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

And the answers should be:

$ \quad  A^{t}_1=\begin{bmatrix}0^t&0\\0&1^t \end{bmatrix}, \quad A^{t}_2=\begin{bmatrix}(-1)^t&0\\0&(-2)^t \end{bmatrix}, \quad A^{t}_3=\begin{bmatrix}\delta(t)&\delta(t-1)\\0&\delta(t) \end{bmatrix},\quad A^{t}_4=\begin{bmatrix}\delta(t)&\delta(t-1)&\delta(t-2)\\0&\delta(t)&\delta(t-1)\\0&0&\delta(t)\end{bmatrix},\quad A^{t}_5=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0^t+2^t&-0^t+2^t\\-0^t+2^t&0^t+2^t \end{bmatrix}$

where
$   \delta(j)=0^{|j|}=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1 \ \text{for} \ j = 0\\
                  0 \ \text{for} \ j \neq  0\\
                                  \end{array}
              \right.
$

How is this done? What kind of sorcery is this?

I've checked on the net but all I could find were tricky mathematical definitions, while I'm looking for a simple "how to".

Help me Stackexchange, you are my only hope.

Comment: It's a capital $^T$ for transposition. OP: have you tried just writing down a few terms in the sequence? e.g. $A_1^2, A_1^3$ and seeing what you get?

Comment: No it's not the transpose. The answers are shown below. It has to do with the response to discrete time autonomous linear systems. the "$t$" could just as well be another random variable like $"k"$ or whatever.

Comment: @Arthur I agree, terrible idea! But look at $A_4$ and $A_4^t$, that's not how the transpose works!

Comment: Have you tried diagonalisation. The first few are obvious

Comment: This just means for $t$ being an integer  $A^t=A\cdot A \cdot\ldots \cdot A$ ($t$-times)

Comment: Compute the first powers by hand and look for a pattern.

Comment: "It's a capital  $^T$ for transposition". Not necessarily, in France a lot of people tends to write $^t$. But the use of a capital letter is indeed recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a diagonal $n\times n$ matrix, it is not very hard to check that
$$\bigl(D(a_1,\dots,a_n)\bigr)^t=D(a_1^t,\dots,a_n^t).$$

For $A_3$ and $A_4$, just compute the first values to find that
$$A_3^2=0,\quad A_4^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad A_4^3=0.$$

For $A_5$, you can prove by induction that $$A_5^t=\begin{pmatrix}2^{t-1}&2^{t-1}\\ 2^{t-1}&2^{t-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Raise each matrix to powers and use math induction to prove the given results.

The notation should not bother you if you use your own notation instead of those $\delta$ stuff.

Some like $A_1$ and $A_2$ are obvious and others take some time but are not too bad.